# Random mysql connection errors and other problems after server and wordpress migration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

I have migrated my wordpress site to a new Debian 7 x64 VPS. After the migration I sometimes randomly receive "Error Establishing a Database Connection". Though I have tried various methods to fix this problem I still get the random errors.

Additionally the only way to access the db is only by the Adminer wp plugin after I login to wordpress and via mysql command line. Adminer will not let me login if I use it as php script out of wordpress. I use mysql 5.5 with nginx 1.4.1 and php5-fpm with unix socket.

Strangely enough the posts are not shown immediately after publish also after the migration. MySQL logs are always empty. The only workaround I found was that I had to manually restart the mysql daemon after the error in order to temporarily fix it until the next random error.

In my mysql user passwords I include symbols. Is this somehow affecting the behaviour of the mysql server or the database connection? Should I try to repair the database?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Same here. I hate nginx so much that I'm moving back to apache :(